# R script using runif() and rbern()

Tags: r

[image]

This needs to be solved using R script: Use runif() and rbern() to follow the above generative recipe that will generate 4000 draws (i.e. realizations) of the "C" random variable representing the processing time of an individual car. Of the 4,000 draws you have generated, what percentage of the draws have a car processing time GREATER than 6 minutes? Enter your percentage as a decimal with three significant digits (e.g. enter 0.342 for 34.2%).

I am just trying 4 draws to begin with and have this code.

```
for (i in 1:4) {   
   rainTime = runif(n=4, min=1, max = 2) 
   Wash = runif(n=4, min=2, max=3)
   A=Wash
   preWash = runif(n=4, min=1, max=2)
   B=preWash
   rainFlag = rbern(4, 0.5)   
   x = rainFlag*rainTime    
   C=A+B+x   
   result =max(C)  
   filter(C,C>6)
   outputMessage = paste0("Result=", result)   
   print(outputMessage) 
}
```

I am not sure how I would get instances where C>6 mins and then add a percentage on top of that.  From the below code, I do get a single occurrence where the value of C exceeds 6 mins.

Comment: So what did you try? Show us the code

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't an oracle that does your homework for you.

Comment: I am a beginner in the R programming and that's why getting some help

Comment: for (i in 1:4) {
  rainTime = runif(n=4, min=1, max = 2)
  Wash = runif(n=4, min=2, max=3)
  A=Wash
  preWash = runif(n=4, min=1, max=2)
  B=preWash
  rainFlag = rbern(4, 0.5)
  x = rainFlag*rainTime  
  C=A+B+x
  outputMessage = paste0("C=", C)
  print(outputMessage)
}

Comment: This is what I have so far, I just tried with 4 draws

Comment: That's a good start. Can you please edit your question to add that information (formatted as code, by indenting 4 spaces *or* surrounding with triple-back-single-quotes ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with trying to get some help, but you didn't really ask a question so much as copy-pasted a homework problem. It might help to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: ok, thank you, I have updated the question with my code

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve:  Thank you for your responses

```
> library("tidyverse") 
> set.seed(111)
> rainTime = runif(n=4000, min=1, max = 2) 
> Wash = runif(n=4000, min=2, max=3)   
> A=Wash   
> preWash = runif(n=4000, min=1, max=2)  
> B=preWash   
> rainFlag = rbern(n=4000, prob=0.5)   
> x = rainFlag*rainTime
> C=A+B+x    
> result =ifelse(C >6, 1,0)   
> count1 = sum(result==1)  
> length(result) 
> proportion6 =  round(sum(result==1)/length(result),3)  
> proportion6
```